# Laravel `has` relationship count using parent column value

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I want to grab records whose relation count is less than the value of a parent column.

I have a model called `Dealer`, which has an attribute called `daily_assign_limit`.

In the `Dealer` model, I have this relationship:

```
public function assigns()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Assign::class);
}

public function assigns_today()
{
    return $this->assigns()->whereDate('created_at', today());
}
```

I have tried to query the dealers who haven't reached their `daily_assign_limit` using this method:

```
    return Dealer::query()
        ->has('assigns_today', '<', 'daily_assign_limit')
        ->first();
```

It looks like `has` wants an integer instead of a column name. So how would I accomplish this using the parent column rather than a hard coded integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you will have to use [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) + [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-map) to achieve what you want.

```
return Dealer::query()
    ->withCount('assigns_today')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($q) {
        if ($q->assigns_today_count < $q->daily_assign_limit) {
            return $q;
        }
    })->filter(); // filter to remove null values
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured out how to do it by grabbing the results and looping through them, but I would still prefer if it was done via the query builder.

Here is my solution:

```
$dealers = Dealer::query()
    ->withCount('assigns_today')
    ->get();

foreach ($dealers as $dealer) {
    if ($dealer->assigns_today_count < $dealer->daily_assign_limit) {
        return $dealer;
    }
}

return null;
```

If someone can show me how to do this without the `foreach` loop I would be grateful.

Comment: I recommend using Laravel **Collection map()**. Check out my answer below.